# How to display data tables stored in a list in RShiny App and formating the data tables

Tags: r, list, shiny, dt

I want to output several data tables stored in a list in `RShiny`. The list always contains different data tables, so the output in `RShiny` must be dynamic and render. My function, which is called in the `server.R` is called `priceInfo <- function(){}` and generates a list of data tables, where the data tables are in a wide format transformed.

The `priceInfo()` function looks like this: (ATTENTION: This is only an example, the function sometimes returns more than just a list with two data tables)

```
priceInfo <- function(){
  
  set.seed(123)
  dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                        'EEX DEB CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'PEGAS TTF CAL-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        check.names = FALSE)
  
  foo <- function(DT, colname){
    DT <- DT[, c("date", colname), with = FALSE]
    DT <- DT %>%
      mutate(month = format(date, '%b'), 
             date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = colname) %>%
      relocate(`01`, .after = month)
    
    ## Calculate monthly and quarterly mean values: ##
    DT <- setDT(DT)[, monthAvg := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -1]
    DT <- DT[, quartAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/3)]
    DT <- DT[, yearAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/12)]
    
    ## Round all values of the data table to 2 digits: ##
    DT <- DT %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
    
  }
  
  l.testList <- lapply(names(dt.data)[names(dt.data) != "date"], 
                       foo, DT = dt.data)
  setNames(l.testList, names(dt.data)[names(dt.data) != "date"])
  
  
  
}
```

I tried the following to display all data tables of the list:

**SERVER:**

```
server <- function(input, output, session){
  tables <- priceInfo()$l.testList
  
  output$maPriceInformationTABLES <- renderUI({
  tableList <- imap(tables, ~ {
    tagList(
      h4(.y), # Note we can sprinkle in other UI elements
      tableOutput(outputId = paste0("table_", .y))
    )
  })
  tagList(tableList)
  })

  # Now render each output
  iwalk(tables, ~{
    output_name <- paste0("table_", .y)
    output[[output_name]] <- renderTable(.x)
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

**UI:**

```
uiOutput(outputId = "maPriceInformationTABLES")
```

Basically, the output of the tables works almost as I would like. **BUT:**
I would like to use `DT::renderDataTable({})` because all tables are relatively wide and are never fully displayed (there a missing 11 columns).

What changes do I have to make to ensure that all data tables are displayed correctly?

I  also have an idea of what the data tables should look like at the end (here is just an example for a single table):

```
output$maPriceInformationTABLES<- DT::renderDataTable({

  DT::datatable(dt.tables, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe', # 'display cell-border stripe'
                options = list(pageLength = 10, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
                               columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(0,1,2,3), width = '200px')),
                               initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                                 "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#007d3c', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                  "}")
                        )
          )
})
```

---

---

**EDIT:**

When changing `tableOutput` to `DTOutput` and `renderTable` to `renderDT`, then the tables looks like this:
[image]

Here again, the tables are not displayed correct (missing 11 columns).

I would also like to have the data tables as follows (the code above is already for a single data table):

[image]

And I don't know how to apply this formatting to all of the data tables.

`pageLength = 12`doesn't work, here a screenshot:

[image]

Comment: I don't understand the problem (but I didn't carefully read your long post). You just want datatables instead of ordinary tables?

Comment: I have a list that contains several data tables. I would then output these data tables one after the other in RShiny, taking into account that the data tables are in a wide format.

Comment: And what is the difficulty you encounter?

Comment: The problem is described in my question above! I have already managed to output the data tables in RShiny, but they are not displayed completely (columns are missing) and the names are not given for each data table, only numbers (1, 2, etc.). SEE ATTACHED GRAPHIC

Comment: OK, I have solved the problem with the names, but not the problem of displaying the whole (wide) data tables

Comment: Datatables have an option `scrollX`, to add a horizontal scrollbar to wide tables. Would it be satisfactory for you?

Comment: I know, I'm using ```scrollX``` in the last code-part of my question as you can see! But this part is generated only for **one** data table, and I need to do this for all data tables which are occuring in my list. And that is my problem. Please read my question, then you will see what I have, what I want and what I have already done but not for multiple data tables.

Comment: Sorry. The point I don't understand is why don't you simply replace `tableOutput` with `DTOutput` and `renderTable` with `renderDT` (with the appropriate body). That does not work?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent no it doesn't display all columns, see my edit!

Comment: Hmm strange. Unless I'm blind, you don't provide the `priceInfo` function in your post. Could you add it, so that I can try to reproduce?

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent I added the code at the beginning of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is what I think you are after:

```
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(data.table)
library(DT)
library(shiny)

priceInfo <- function(){
  set.seed(123)
  dt.data <- data.table(date = seq(as.Date('2020-01-01'), by = '1 day', length.out = 365),
                        'DEB Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'DEB Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'DEB Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'DEB Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'ATB Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATB Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'ATB Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATB Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'TTF Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'TTF Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'TTF Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'TTF Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'NCG Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'NCG Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'NCG Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'NCG Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'AUTVTP Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'AUTVTP Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'AUTVTP Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'AUTVTP Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'ATW Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATW Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'ATW Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'ATW Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'BRN Cal-2019' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'BRN Cal-2021' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'BRN Cal-2022' = rnorm(365, 2, 1), 'BRN Cal-2023' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        'FEUA MDEC1' = rnorm(365, 2, 1),
                        check.names = FALSE)
  
  foo <- function(DT, colname){
    DT <- DT[, c("date", colname), with = FALSE]
    DT <- DT %>%
      mutate("2020" = format(date, '%b'), 
             date = format(date, '%d')) %>%
      tidyr::pivot_wider(names_from = date, values_from = colname) %>%
      relocate(`01`, .after = "2020")
    
    ## Calculate monthly and quarterly mean values: ##
    DT <- setDT(DT)[, monthAvg := rowMeans(.SD, na.rm = TRUE), .SDcols = -1]
    DT <- DT[, quartAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/3)]
    DT <- DT[, yearAvg := mean(monthAvg), ceiling(seq_len(nrow(DT))/12)]
    
    ## Round all values of the data table to 2 digits: ##
    DT <- DT %>% mutate_if(is.numeric, round, 2)
    
  }
  
  l.testList <- lapply(names(dt.data)[names(dt.data) != "date"], foo, DT = dt.data)
  l.testList <- setNames(l.testList, names(dt.data)[names(dt.data) != "date"])
  
  return(l.testList)
  
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  uiOutput(outputId = "maPriceInformationTABLES")
)

server <- function(input, output, session){
  tables <- priceInfo()
  
  output$maPriceInformationTABLES <- renderUI({
    tableList <- imap(tables, ~ {
      tagList(
        h4(.y), # Note we can sprinkle in other UI elements
        DTOutput(outputId = paste0("table_", .y))
      )
    })
    tagList(lapply(tableList, br))
  })
  
  # Now render each output
  iwalk(tables, ~{
    output_name <- paste0("table_", .y)
    output[[output_name]] <- renderDT({
      DT::datatable(.x, rownames = FALSE, escape = FALSE, class = 'cell-border stripe', # 'display cell-border stripe'
                    options = list(pageLength = 12, autoWidth = TRUE, scrollX = TRUE,
                                   initComplete = JS("function(settings, json) {",
                                                     "$(this.api().table().header()).css({'background-color': '#007d3c', 'color': '#fff'});",
                                                     "}")
                    )
      )
    })
  })
}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image: result]

Comment: What did you change to get the scrollbars? I don't see the problem in the OP's code. I suspect she uses an old version of DT.

Comment: I wasn't able to reproduce the scrollbar problem. This is using latest CRAN version of `DT` (0.16).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Would it be possible to change ONLY the column name of the first column from ```month``` to ```2020```?

Comment: The definiton of the column width was part of your code: `columnDefs = list(list(className = 'dt-center', targets = c(0,1,2,3), width = '200px')),` just delete this line

Comment: you always want the first column to be 2020? or depending on the year?

Comment: Yes, always 2020

Comment: I can think of two little things that I would like to add:
**1.** How can I add a little space between the individual tables?
**2.** Each data table in the list has a total of 13 rows (1st row and the other rows from ```Jan``` to ```Dec```). Would it be possible that the entire data table is always displayed, because here it only goes until ```Oct```. I have already tried ```options = list(pageLength = 12, ...)```, unfortunately that doesn't work.

Comment: `pageLength = 12` should do it.

Comment: ```pageLength = 12``` gives "Show 12 entries" at the top left, but the table is only shown to me until Oct.

Comment: Just added another screenshot using `pageLength = 12`. Please re-check your procedure.

Comment: You can add space between the tables using `br` - edited once more.

Comment: Thank you! Now there is a space between the data tables. But ```pageLength = 12``` doesn't work, I have added a Screenshot in my question above.

Comment: It seems you are using a different dataset. There is no table "EEX DEB CAL-2021" in the above code. Please point out when you are modifying the code or using other data - otherwise no one is able to reproduce the behaviour! Are you sure that this table has 12 rows? `Showing 1 to 10 of 10 entries` as mentioned in your screenshot suggests something else........

Comment: YES, all data tables have 12 rows from Jan to Dec. No it is the same dataset but only with different column names, but that doesn't matter, it has to work anyway. In addition, the above code for ```dt.data``` is only an example. This data table always looks different and can have more than just 3 columns. BUT: the data is always available from Jan to Dec (I always have these rows).

Comment: I have restarted my computer, and now its working. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: Once again - your screenshot shows, that this table is only provided 10 rows. Using my above example **without modifying** is showing 12 rows per table. For me that's it. You can check it via `lapply(priceInfo(), nrow)`